# Openshift node.js: do I need to load ssl certificates in the web console or in the application?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openshift

In order to run HTTPS on my `node.js` application, I load the certificates within my application. It works fine on my laptop. I am now pushing my work on OpenShift, but the app does not work anymore (ligatures.net).

The Openshift [documentation][1] says certificates can be loaded via the web console. So do I need to load my SSL certificates within my application or should I rely on the web console instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the ssl certificates in the OpenShift web console, as the ssl termination happens on the proxy that is part of the node that your gear is on.

Comment: I have loaded the certificate in the web console, but the issue remains (503 service unavailable). Am I supposed to load the certificates in my application too? Else, how do I create the https server? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the part of your code where you are specifying your port & ip address that you are listening on?

Comment: I'll create another question